# How can I overiride UIcollectioView Delegate and datasource method in its own class

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I had made a class of UICollectionView and I want to override its behaviour,so that whenever I want to show collectionView I make Class of UIView i.e UICollectionView.

Currently I'm doing it like this....

```
#import "CustomCollectionView.h"

@implementation CustomCollectionView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    NSLog(@"");
}
return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

- (void)customInit {

}
```

So in customInit method i want to set the size of Cell and want to override datasource method too....

Comment: The description is confusing. Is CustomCollectionView a subclass of UIView or UICollectionView?